# libxkbcommon.so.0: no version information available after installing VSCode update

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After updating VSCode to v.1.53.0 I am getting following message on opening VSCode:

> /usr/share/code/bin/../code: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0: no version information available (required by /usr/share/code/bin/../code)

On giving command `code --verbose` I get following logs: [logs](https://jsfiddle.net/ehjw7f1y/)

I cannot update current Ubuntu version due to limited admin rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `code --verbose` you will see real problem:

```
[main 2021-04-16T11:44:45.671Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
/usr/share/code/code --verbose --no-sandbox: relocation error: /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/spdlog/build/Release/spdlog.node: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareEPKc, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

It can't find symbol `basic_string::compare`

`echo _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareEPKc | demangle`

So to run visual studio code on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
You just need to copy libstdc++.so.6.0.28 and libstdc++.so.6
to /usr/share/code from ubuntu 20.04 LTS

You can get libstdc++.so.6.0.28 (md5=0e7d34a60136c0cd150917ed099980f2) for example from [this deb file](https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc%2B%2B6_10.2.0-5ubuntu1%7E20.04_amd64.deb)

Here simple script to do it for you

```
#!/bin/sh

wget https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc%2B%2B6_10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb -R libstdc++6_10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb .
sudo cp -P usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* /usr/share/code/
```

[file](https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc%2B%2B6_10.3.0-1ubuntu1%7E20.04_amd64.deb) version changed in wikimedia.org so new script:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc%2B%2B6_10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb --no-check-certificate
dpkg-deb -R libstdc++6_10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb .
sudo cp -P usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* /usr/share/code/
```

md5sum of new libstdc++.so.6.0.28 604ec2999aeb3aadd0e96103fd4b5e5d

Then just type `code`

[image]

ps: very good font for vscode [JetBrains Mono](https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc%2B%2B6_10.3.0-1ubuntu1%7E20.04_amd64.deb)

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded my VSCode to lower version. Apparently you can access previous versions of VSCode from it's website but the [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52)'s font was too big form me to see.

[image]

Still if someone does come across any other alternative please share.
Leaving this here for others.